# Android Room exception when sorting

Tags: android, android-room

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM registration_products ORDER BY isFinished :idSorting, id :statusSorting;")    
public List<RegistrationProduct> getProducts(String idSorting, String statusSorting);
```

idSorting is underlined and statusSorting is underlined too. idSorting is ASC or DESC and statusSorting is ASC or DESC. I don't want to create extra functions. Pls, help!

> Exception: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR]
>   SQL error or missing database (no such function: finished)

Here is what I have now:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM registration_products ORDER BY isFinished ASC, id ASC;")
public List<RegistrationProduct> getProductsASCASC();

@Query("SELECT * FROM registration_products ORDER BY isFinished DESC, id ASC;")
public List<RegistrationProduct> getProductsDESCASC();

@Query("SELECT * FROM registration_products ORDER BY isFinished ASC, id DESC;")
public List<RegistrationProduct> getProductsASCDESC();

@Query("SELECT * FROM registration_products ORDER BY isFinished DESC, id DESC;")
public List<RegistrationProduct> getProductsDESCDESC();
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get sorted list, by using 2 columns: SELECT * FROM registration_products ORDER BY isFinished DESC, id DESC;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [SQLite CASE](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-case/) expressions:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM registration_products ORDER BY isFinished CASE WHEN :idSorting = 'ASC' THEN ASC ELSE DESC END, id CASE WHEN :statusSorting = 'ASC' THEN ASC ELSE DESC END")
public List<RegistrationProduct> getProducts(String idSorting, String statusSorting);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to do it with `SimpleQuery`.

```
@RawQuery
List<RegistrationProduct> getProductions(query: SupportSQLiteQuery);
```

And then you build your query manually.

```
public SupportSqliteQuery getProducts(String idSorting, String statusSorting) {
    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM registration_products ");
    List<Object> args = new ArrayList<>();

    queryBuilder.append("ORDER BY ");

    queryBuilder.append("isFinished ? ");
    args.add(statusSorting);

    queryBuilder.append(", ");

    queryBuilder.append("id ? ");
    args.add(statusSorting);

    queryBuilder.append(";");

    Object[] argsArray = args.toArray(new Object[args.size()]);
    return new SimpleSQLiteQuery(queryBuilder.toString(), argsArray);
}
```

With this approach, you can avoid writing a complex query and include more logic in the future (if you want). You could also use enums to avoid passing invalid values for order in the method.

Comment: As I understand, getProducts function must be in outer class, for example:  @RawQuery
List<RegistrationProduct> getProductions(query: SupportSQLiteQuery); must be in inner dao class, but getProducts function must be in repository class, not the best solution I think, again this will be an extra function. But thanks for your help!))